# Null check OR isEmpty Check

Tags: soql, list, null, empty

I have checked many posts but still not clear.
A SOQL query returns a list but if SOQL finds no records then it will return an empty list or it will be null?

When should i go for isEmpty check or when for null check?

Thanks

Comment: Also, see http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/77173.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The straight SOQL `accounts = [select id, .. from Account ...]`

always returns a list

You can usually avoid even having to test for list empty by coding your methods to accept lists as arguments and otherwise use for loop processing as in

```
for (Account a: accounts) { // if accounts is empty, loop does nothing
    // do work
}

someReturnType myMethod(Account[] accounts) {
   for (Account a: account) {
      // do work
   }
}
```

Otherwise use `accounts.isEmpty()` or `accounts.size() == 0`

testing for null is unnecessary in a well-designed application that uses lists and maps as the core internal data structures. Personally, if I ever get a null value for a list, I prefer the null exception to occur during unit testing as it means I didn't design my code correctly to operate with lists throughout (or I forgot to init a list to empty).

*N.B.*

For DML, you never need to test for list empty as SFDC will do nothing if passed an empty list

Use:

```
update accounts; // does not burn a DML limit if list is empty
```

Don't use (wastes a line of code):

```
if (!accounts.isEmpty())
   update accounts;
```

Comment: Great!! but in the last scenario, suppose i am adding some elements to list using add method after some processing on data and finally i need to insert this list.  In this case also SFDC will do nothing if passed an empty list?

Comment: that is correct; SFDC DML methods accept lists as arguments and if list is empty, the DML statement simply returns and does not consume any limits

Comment: OK thanks!! one last Question, In what case we can get a null list? Or when should we check for NULL on list?

Comment: @RamanSuri No SOQL query will return a NULL list. So you'd just check for NULL if other code generated the list for you, say from an apex method you didn't code. As @cropredy mentioned in his answer, if you do generate List or Map, don't return NULL, return an empty one so that the `for ( Account a : accounts )` idiom works regardless. Hope that helps!

Comment: @RamanSuri if you ever study the `fflib` Separation of Concerns GitHub library, you'll see that some of the best coders in the business pass lists around from method to method.

Answer (score 7):

Generally speaking, null values *should* be rare, and you should treat them as such. The results of a query always results in a list, even though it may be an empty list. Querying a checkbox field from the database will always be true or false, never null. Calling XmlNode.getChildElements() will never return null, but may return empty lists.

There are a few rare exceptions when you do need to check for null values. For example, when you make a variable transient, its not stored in the view state, so you usually need to implement lazy loading by checking for null first, and when you bind to a multi-select picklist, the list will always be either null or non-empty.

These are the exceptions to the rule, and you should learn them. Whenever you declare a list of your own, you should always assign a non-null value to it, which may be either a new list, or a list generated from a query. You should prefer to initialize those lists in a constructor, so that all your initialization code is in one place.

Generally speaking, when I use a method I'm not familiar with, I try calling it with a few different parameters to see if I can get a null value back instead of a list. I test it independently to verify its behavior. If it doesn't return a null, then I presume it never will. Just remember that *most* of the API avoids returning null values, or has a way to check beforehand. Most of the best design patterns for code avoid nulls using various techniques. As you gain experience, you'll learn those rare times when you *must* check for null, and find ways to code structures to reduce the null checks you need to make.

Comment: the one exception here is when you use "getSObjects" on a subquery that was empty it will return null.....Found that out the hard way.

Comment: @Eric I found that out the hard way too this week. Blasted `getSObjects` will return the dreaded `null` like no tomorrow.

Comment: @Eric yeah - I forgot about that one; my code even has a comment next to the null check as to why I had to insert the conditional so I didn't remove it in some future hygiene cycle

Comment: @Eric Yeah, the problem is the SObject object. It has magical properties as long as you're still in "SObject land", which happens to operate as a null coalescing operator. For example, `User u = [SELECT Manager.Manager.Manager.Id FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()]; System.debug(u.Manager.Manager.Manager.Id)` won't crash, even if the user has no manager. The dynamic methods don't get that same protection. Like I said, there's some rare occurrences where you do have to watch out, but generally nulls are uncommon.

Answer (score -4):

The best way is to keep a check on list size and null check both. 
Here is an example -

```
 List<Account> accList = [select id,name from account where name='test'];

 if(accList.size()>0 && accList!=null){
      //make things happen!!
    }
```

Comment: f the null check was needed (it isn't in this case) it would need to come before the size check to avoid an NPE.