# Automatically add ProductB once ProductA is manually added to the opportunity

Tags: opportunity, opportunity-lineitem, pricebookentry

I have been trying to get this trigger to work and it has been impossible... ugh... maybe you guys can help me.

I have created the following trigge with the help of some freinds under "Opporunity Products" triggers. The issue is that the second product is not being added automatically to the opportunity once the first product is added manually. I don't understand why it is not working. Can you guys help me please?

```
trigger Attempt1 on OpportunityLineItem (after insert) {
    List<OpportunityLineItem> OpportunityLineItems = new List<OpportunityLineItem>(); 
for(OpportunityLineItem item: [
   SELECT OpportunityId, Name 
   FROM OpportunityLineItem
   WHERE Id = :Trigger.new AND Name = 'Car_Filter_Plus']) {
        OpportunityLineItems.add(new OpportunityLineItem(
            OpportunityId = item.OpportunityId, 
            PricebookEntryId ='01eE000000QopleIAD',
            Quantity = 1,
            UnitPrice = 25)
        );
}
}
```

Comment: I think there are couple of things wrong with this, but I don't know the exact syntax you need. You jump right into the creation of the new oli, it feels like you should do some sort of check to see if your query actually returned a value or not. Then if it does do the create.

Comment: How do I do that? I'm new to this. Trying to learn

Comment: what is the 2nd product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was thinking when I thought to check but I suppose it's not needed if sfdcfox is right: [list.IsEmpty() vs list.Size() > 0 vs list != null](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/77173/list-isempty-vs-list-size-0-vs-list-null)

I think you're simply missing insert at the end. I think this overall could be optimized by doing the action in before insert. That way you can check if your product Car_Filter_Plus is in the list to insert and then add your new oli to the list and then you add all the products at once. Because the way your approach is now it's like your doing a insert twice in the same transaction. User creates OpportunuityLineItem record -> check the record that was created -> create another OpportunityLineItem record. You might hit some limits down the road if you're doing some more things after the OLi is created.

Example:

```
trigger Attempt1 on OpportunityLineItem (after insert) {
List<OpportunityLineItem> oliList = new List<OpportunityLineItem>(); 
for( OpportunityLineItem item: [SELECT  OpportunityId, 
                                        Name 
                                FROM    OpportunityLineItem
                                WHERE   Id = :Trigger.new AND 
                                        Name = 'Car_Filter_Plus'])
 {
  oliList.add(new OpportunityLineItem(
    OpportunityId = item.OpportunityId, 
    PricebookEntryId ='01eE000000QopleIAD',
    Quantity = 1,
    UnitPrice = 25)
  );
 }
 Insert oliList;
}
```

Comment: I tried that code, but the second product didn't get added once the first one was added. :(