# Null object Error in a test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, pdf

I currently get 56% code coverage. Getting a Null object error

```
public class CustomerInfoSheet {
    public String PrintOut { get; set; }
    public String LookupID;
    public String LookupType;


     public CustomerInfoSheet() {
        LookupID = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        LookupType = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('l');
        List<Account> a;

        PrintOut = '';      


        if (LookupType == 'a' ){
            a = [select Name,  Industry, Type from Account where Id = :LookupID];
        } 
        if (LookupType == 'z' ) {
            a = [select Name, Industry, Type from Account where Zone__c = :LookupID];
        }

       //Industry
         {myPicklist.clear();
             Schema.DescribeFieldResult field = Account.Industry.getDescribe();
            for (Schema.PicklistEntry f : field.getPicklistValues()){
             myPicklist.add(f.getLabel());}
             }
         string test104 = '';
         for (String str : myPicklist)
         {test104 += str + ' -/- ';}
         test104 = test104.removeEnd(' -/- ');
         String Industrylist = String.valueOf('No Value Selected - Please Select one now: '+ test104);



        String CustomerName = '';

        String Industry = '';

        if (!a.isEmpty()){
            for (Account CustomerInfo : a) {

                CustomerName = CustomerInfo.Name;

                 if (!(CustomerInfo.Industry == null)) { Industry = CustomerInfo.Industry; } else { Industry = Industrylist;}

                PrintOut += '<div style="page-break-after:always;">';
                PrintOut += '<strong>Company: </strong>';
                PrintOut += CustomerName;
                 PrintOut += '<br/>';
                PrintOut += '<br/>';
                PrintOut += '<strong>Industry: </strong>';
                PrintOut += Industry;
              }
        }
    }    
}
```

---

```
@IsTest
    public class CustomerInfoSheetTest {

    static testMethod void testCustomerInfoSheet() {

            Account acct = new Account();
            acct.Name='TestAccount';                 
            acct.Industry = 'AG';
            insert acct;

        Test.startTest();
         PageReference pageRef = Page.CustomerInfoSheet; 

            system.debug('account inserted '+acct.Id);
            pageRef.getParameters().put('id', acct.Id);
            pageRef.getParameters().put('l', acct.Name); 
            system.debug('ID: '+acct.Id + ' Name: '+acct.Name);
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
        system.debug('pageRef: '+pageRef);

            CustomerInfoSheet ac = new CustomerInfoSheet();
            system.debug('CustomerInfoSheet'+ac);
        Test.stopTest();    
    }    
}
```

Comment: We cannot see the class you are testing, so it is impossible to help you as this question is currently written.

Comment: Also note: *Verifying that your code works as you expect it to work is **the most important part of unit testing**. It’s also one of the things that Force.com developers commonly neglect. Unit tests that do not verify the results of the code aren’t true unit tests. They are commonly referred to as **[smoke tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_testing#Smoke_testing_in_software_development), which aren’t nearly as effective or informative as true unit tests**.* -
 [How to Write Good Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests)

Comment: I updated the code somewhat. There is alot so I tried to keep it simple. It all works great and does what is required. Just need to test the output (at least that's my understanding)

Comment: @CameronHouser So, you need to set page parameters, it looks like. To test everything means to test every possible branch.

Comment: working on it,  its 11pm so I am signing off tonight. @sdcfox, I tried my hand with the page parameters, I have not figured out what I am doing wrong yet. Any pointers would be welcome.

Comment: Updated Test class (getting a null object error now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your help. The problem was that I was not passing the parameter the if statement was looking for. You can see it below: pageRef.getParameters().put('id', String.valueOf(acct.Id));
pageRef.getParameters().put('l', 'a'); It works now

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the error probably occurred here:

```
    if (!a.isEmpty()){
```

You have two different possible parameter values, but if you make it past both parameters without a valid path, a will still be null. As a side note, you do not need to check if a [list is empty before using it](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/77173/list-isempty-vs-list-size-0-vs-list-null) in a for-loop (the loop simply will not execute). As such, you should change it as follows:

```
    if(a != null) {
```

---

In the general case, you should set the page reference first, then add parameters to it:

```
Test.setCurrentPageReference(Page.CustomerInfoSheet);
ApexPages.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('id',acct.id);
ApexPages.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('l',acct.Name);
```

Comment: @CameronHouser Still, fix your if statement.