# List index out of bounds: 0 in IF condition

Tags: apex, after-trigger

[image]

There is an error on line 36: List index out of bounds: 0

Why am I getting this error when I'm not actually using the value, instead I'm just checking if it's null?

Comment: Please use text for code instead of images. It's more accessible and makes it easier for people to make small corrections. Screenshots with long lines are functionally unreadable.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is just how lists work in `Apex`. If you do not know an index is in the list, and you try to retrieve it, you get this type of error. You must first check the list is not empty to use a 0 index, and check its size more specifically before using any greater index.

See also ['System.ListException: List index out of bounds' error](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385743&type=1):

> ### Resolution
>
> If we attempt to access an element at row 0, The code will throw an error if  no data exist at row 0. It is a  good practice to check whether there are records  in the list before accessing any element from that list.
>
> #### Check if list is empty
>
> Before referring to the 0th index of list you must perform a check on whether the list is empty or not. Whenever you try to access records from list first check if its empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

As [@Adrian](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2995/adrian-larson) mentioned, in your code you have only checked for the size of `caseList`, but not for `userRecord`.

If the query at line 31 does not return any records, then `userRecord` will be empty. Probably this is the reason you are getting the error.

Also the first two condition checking are redundant,

```
caseList != null && caseList.size() > 0
```

Instead, you can use the new [Safe Navigation Operator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SafeNavigationOperator.htm) like below, assuming you have initialised the lists beforehand:

```
caseList?.size() > 0
```

Check out this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/77173/list-isempty-vs-list-size-0-vs-list-null) to find more about the different ways to check for an empty list in apex.

Try using the following as well in your if condition:

```
userRecord?.size() > 0
```

Happy learning!